# UPDATE records using CASE - SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

My Original table has a value like this:

```
   ID           TELPHONE
  ----------- --------------
  1923        6276572   
  1949        2126670825
  2125
  1926        12126670825
```

I'm executing below query to get expected result as below:

```
UPDATE #T  
SET     TELEPHONE = CASE  
                    WHEN CHARINDEX('1212', TELEPHONE, 1) = 0 THEN 
  '1212'+TELEPHONE

        WHEN CHARINDEX('212', TELEPHONE , 1) = 1 THEN '1'+TELEPHONE

        ELSE TELEPHONE

                END 
 WHERE (STATE LIKE '%UU%' OR STATE LIKE '%U&P%' OR STATE LIKE '%UTTER%') AND 
LEN(TELEPHONE) <= 10
```

MY expectation:

```
 ID           TELPHONE
 ----------- --------------
 1923        12126276572   
 1949        12126670825
 2125
 1926        12126670825
```

However, I'm getting like below(which is wrong)

```
 id      TELPHONE      
 ----------- --------------   
  1923        12126276572
 1949        12122126670825             
 2125        1212                         
 1926        12126670825
```

what am I doing wrong. And How ro get expected result?

Comment: Honestly the output looks like exactly what you have coded. I suspect is RowID 2125 that you have an issue with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did correct update with this (I omitted your where conditions):

```
  UPDATE TELE  SET TELPHONE = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('212', TELPHONE , 1) = 1 THEN '1'+TELPHONE
                              WHEN CHARINDEX('1212', TELPHONE, 1) = 0 AND TELPHONE<>'' THEN '1212'+TELPHONE                            
                        ELSE TELPHONE
                        END
```

;
Output:

```
+------+-------------+
|  ID  |  TELPHONE   |
+------+-------------+
| 1923 | 12126276572 |
| 1949 | 12126670825 |
| 2125 |             |
| 1926 | 12126670825 |
+------+-------------+
```

I think performances will be better if you can add into WHERE condition AND TELEPHONE<>'' and simplify the case (removing AND in second when of my case):

```
UPDATE TELE  SET TELPHONE = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('212', TELPHONE , 1) = 1 THEN '1'+TELPHONE
                              WHEN CHARINDEX('1212', TELPHONE, 1) = 0   THEN '1212'+TELPHONE                               
                        ELSE TELPHONE
                        END                  
   WHERE --(STATE LIKE '%UU%' OR STATE LIKE '%U&P%' OR STATE LIKE '%UTTER%') 
       --AND 
        LEN(TELPHONE) <= 10 AND TELPHONE<>'';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `case` is matching rows you don't want it to in the first expression.  Rearrange your `case` so that your check for `212` comes first as this is a positive only match and if that is not met, only then check for the negative match on `1212`:

```
declare @t table (
                 ID       int
                ,TELEPHONE nvarchar(50)
                 );
insert into @t
values (1923,'6276572'),
       (1949,'2126670825'),
       (2125,''),
       (1926,'12126670825');

select Telephone
        ,case when charindex('212',TELEPHONE,1) = 1
                then '1'+TELEPHONE
              when charindex('1212',TELEPHONE,1) = 0
                   and TELEPHONE <> ''
                then '1212'+TELEPHONE
              else TELEPHONE
              end as TelephoneNew
       ,charindex('212',TELEPHONE,1) as [212Match]
       ,charindex('1212',TELEPHONE,1) as [1212Match]
from @t
```

Output:

```
+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|  Telephone  | TelephoneNew | 212Match | 1212Match |
+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
|     6276572 |  12126276572 |        0 |         0 |
|  2126670825 |  12126670825 |        1 |         0 |
|             |              |        0 |         0 |
| 12126670825 |  12126670825 |        2 |         1 |
+-------------+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: why blank is getting update ? That is ID =  2125 ; should not update.I wanted this as blank.Any other solutions as I have 1millon blank records 
 to keep as it is?

Comment: Because you have a negative check in your `case` statements.  As you can see from the 2 `match` columns, the empty row returns a `0` for both `charindex` checks, so it follows the `case when charindex('1212',TELEPHONE,1) = 0` route, which adds `1212` to the start.  If this isn't how you want it to behave, change your `case` statements.

Comment: @TryingBest  I have added in an additional criteria to check for your blank values.